# Making sql like query using yii2 model

Tags: php, yii2

Am trying to perform this query

```
         $command = $connection->createCommand("
                    SELECT 
                     tbl_checklist.report_val AS item
                     FROM tbl_checks
                        LEFT JOIN tbl_checklist ON tbl_checklist.id = tbl_checks.check_id
                        WHERE truck_id = ".$value->id."
                        "
                 );

         $results = $command->queryAll();
```

THe above works but i would like to perform the same using models

So i have tried

```
$results = TblChecks::find()
           ->leftJoin("tbl_checklist", "tbl_checklist.id = tbl_checks.check_id")
           ->where(["truck_id"=>$value->id])
           ->all();
```

How do i add the `SELECT tbl_checklist.report_val AS item` in the Model flow

Comment: Either use `activeQuery` or try @Yupik suggestion

Answer (score 0):

you should try like this

```
$results = TblChecks::find()->select(["tbl_checklist.report_val AS item","tbl_checks.*"])
           ->leftJoin("tbl_checklist", "tbl_checklist.id = tbl_checks.check_id")
           ->where(["truck_id"=>$value->id])
           ->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, I hope it will solve your issue.

```
$results = TblChecks::find()
       ->select[tbl_checklist.report_val AS item]
       ->leftJoin("tbl_checklist", "tbl_checklist.id = tbl_checks.check_id")
       ->where(["truck_id"=>$value->id])
       ->all();
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use `select()` function:

```
$results = TblChecks::find()
           ->select('tbl_checklist.report_val AS item')
           ->leftJoin("tbl_checklist", "tbl_checklist.id = tbl_checks.check_id")
           ->where(["truck_id"=>$value->id])
           ->all();
```

And add property `$item` in your model.